# R - when using facet_wrap, access the factor within the current facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Consider the following (nonsensical, but working) plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars,                                                                                                                          
       aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = hp)) +                                                                          
       geom_boxplot() +                                                                                                                                                                     
       facet_wrap( ~ am) +                                                                                             
       geom_text(label = "test")
```

[image: Nonsensical graph]

I'd like to pass the value of `am` within each facet to the `label` argument of `geom_text`. So all the labels within the left facet would read "0", all the labels within the right facet would read "1".

How could I achieve this? Simply passing `am` doesn't work, and neither does `.$am`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just provide the label inside `mapping`, like this:

```
  ... + 
  geom_text(aes(label = am))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it as a vector like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl), y = hp)) +                                                                          
  geom_boxplot() +  
  facet_wrap( ~ am) +
  geom_text(label = mtcars$am)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>